# How to keep a counter of default messages in Microsoft Bot Builder and alter Bot response?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to have the azure web app bot respond with a different message after it can't find an answer in the QnA maker knowledge base in 3 tries.

I was wondering what class would I keep the counter in and check it? I also can't figure out what variable the answer is being stored in.
I'm using the question and answer bot template code from Microsoft Azure's web app bot.

Comment: `trying to have the azure web app bot respond with a different message after it can't find an answer in the QnA maker knowledge` In source code of [QnAMakerDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs), currently it seems not provide methods or functions to customize dynamic DefaultMessage in dialog when it can't find an answer.

Comment: Feature request:[Allow custom default return messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/pull/87) is created in github issue.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually nothing difficult..in the BasicQnAMakerDialog, you can find there is a constructor override as below. you can create a property (make sure it's a static) in the class and set the expected value to the property in messagescontroller (" else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)" method.

```
public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : 
base(new QnAMakerService(new 
QnAMakerAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAAuthKey"], 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], 
**noneofabove**, 0.1, 4, 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"])))
            {
            }
```